# Angularjs - Dynamically adding value in module.config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",['ui.router','flow']);
    app.config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
        flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
        target: 'upload.php?type=1',
        testChunks:false,
        singleFile: true,
        permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
        maxChunkRetries: 1,
        chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
        simultaneousUploads: 4
    };  
}]);
```

Above code is working perfectly...

I just want to change target dynamically from $scope variable

i think it should be something like

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",['ui.router','flow']);
    app.config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
        flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
        target: 'upload.php?type=' + $scope.vtype,
        testChunks:false,
        singleFile: true,
        permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
        maxChunkRetries: 1,
        chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
        simultaneousUploads: 4
    };  
}]);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible ways I can think of:

Import $rootScope and set it there:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",['ui.router','flow']);
    app.config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider, $rootScope) {
        flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
            target: 'upload.php?type=' + $rootScope.vtype,
            testChunks:false,
            singleFile: true,
            permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
            maxChunkRetries: 1,
            chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
            simultaneousUploads: 4
        };  
    }
]);
```

and in some controller, you can set it as

```
$rootScope.vtype = something;
```

OR you could write a get/set method inside the provider which would allow you to change a local value.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",['ui.router','flow']);
    app.config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {

        var someLocalValue = 1; // default value

        flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
            target: 'upload.php?type=' + someLocalValue,
            testChunks:false,
            singleFile: true,
            permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
            maxChunkRetries: 1,
            chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
            simultaneousUploads: 4
        };  
        flowFactoryProvider.getSomeLocalValue = function(){
            return someLocalValue;
        };
        flowFactoryProvider.setSomeLocalValue = function(input){
            flowFactoryProvider.defaults.target = 'upload.php?type=' + input;
            someLocalValue = input;
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: hey thanks many thanks for the code buddy.. will i be able to set it from my html page? and if yes then please guide me how?

Comment: no, you will set it in the javascript, not the html.

Comment: The second approach is correct. Avoid `$rootScope` as it sets global state.

Comment: so how will i be able to set the value from controller?

Comment: what you really could use is a service which stores data for use by other services, then you can set defaults there and change it as well if needed. to set it in your controller, you need to inject the object into your controller, and run the set method.

Comment: bro i am unbal eto use it in controller if you give me exact syntax then that would be great
below is my code which is not working
`app.controller('uploadcontroller', function($scope, flowFactoryProvider){
 flowFactoryProvider.setutype('emp');
});`