# App.config AngularJS dynamic

Tags: angularjs, blockui

I have my app.config this way.

```
angular.module('App')
.config(function (blockUIConfig) {
   blockUIConfig.autoInjectBodyBlock = false;
   blockUIConfig.templateUrl = 'assets/bower_components/angular-block-ui/src/angular-block-ui/recibo_preview.html';
   blockUIConfig.autoBlock = false;
});
```

But I need blockUIConfig.templateUrl to be dynamic, more or less like this.

```
angular.module('App')
.config(function (blockUIConfig,$rootScope) {
   blockUIConfig.autoInjectBodyBlock = false;
   blockUIConfig.templateUrl = 'assets/bower_components/angular-block-ui/src/angular-block-ui/'+$rootScope.file;
   blockUIConfig.autoBlock = false;
});
```

Is there any way to associate a $ rootScope variable?

Comment: Example you can provide

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25824437/1172730

Comment: I have not worked the previous example take into account that the injectable blockUIConfig is a constant.